# Are apes our ancestors?

Tags: evolution

I've heard that apes are our ancestors (ranging from chimpanzee to bonobo to gorilla).

Is this true? Can we live side-by-side with our ancestors? I always thought we used to have a common ancestor with them. In which group would our ancestors be? Homini, Hominidae, ...

Comment: Your assumption is correct, the ape remark is a simplification. We have a common ancestor with *all* species, of course, and our most recent common ancestor is with the chimpanzee. That ancestor was, of course, not exactly a chimpanzee.

Comment: And would that ancestor be considered an "ape"?

Comment: It's a common mistake that people think that since chimpanzees don't make guns, they didn't evolve since the split. From there to say that we descended from chimpanzees is a small misstep.

Comment: We **are** apes...

Comment: @ Downvoters...: Please include a reason why the question is being down-voted so that the OP can have a chance to improve the question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Summary: Technically, we *are* apes. Colloquially, we didn't evolve from modern apes: we shared a recent common ancestor with them.**

[image: Ancestors] [[Source](http://www.nature.com/scientificamerican/journal/v16/n2/full/scientificamerican0606-4sp.html)]

From [Comparative genomics of higher primates](http://www.mpg.de/19230/Comparative_genomics#1) ([Max Planck Society](http://www.mpg.de/en)):

> **The common chimpanzee and the bonobo or pygmy chimpanzee are our
> closest living relatives, with whom we share a common ancestor that
> lived 5–7 million years ago.**
>
> **Humans and chimpanzees share a common
> ancestor with gorillas** — the other major species of African apes —
> **that lived 6–8 million years ago**, whereas **the common ancestor shared
> with the Asian orangutans lived 12–16 million years ago**.
>
> Many species that were more closely-related to humans have lived and
> become extinct since the time of the chimpanzee- human ancestor.
> They
> are collectively called hominins.
>
> One hominin is the *Neandertal*, whose
> lineage diverged from ours 300,000–500,000 years ago. Neandertals
> lived in western Eurasia, sometimes alongside our ancestors, until
> they became extinct around 30,000 years ago.

**More:**

- [The genetical history of humans and the great apes](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1046/j.1365-2796.2002.00907.x/abstract;jsessionid=EC6053649E308781C6DB03AEFA2B6160.d02t01)

Comment: I hope my added summary is OK.

Answer (score 7):

I found this diagram a while back that helps visualize how this all works.

We are not descended from apes. We are descended from an ape-like ancestor. As David say, people simplify by saying we "descended from apes".

source: http://whozoo.org/mammals/Primates/primatephylogeny.htm

[image: Primate Phylogeny]